# If-Then-Else statement in ModelBuilder has improper syntax

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, python-parser, syntax, error-000989

I have a model that converts a road network into a different schema for a different program. In one step of the model I am converting values for a field "Class".  I wrote an If-Then-Else statement in Python but my syntax is off.  Here is the code:

```
def gst(old_value):
    if old_value == 'P00':
        return A91:    
    elif old_value == 'P09':
        return A91:     
    elif old_value == 'P01':
        return A89: 
    elif old_value == 'P02':
        return A90:
    elif old_value == 'P03':
        return A90:
    elif old_value == 'P04':
        return A40:  
    elif old_value == 'P05':
        return A40:
    elif old_value == 'P06':
        return A40:  
    elif old_value == 'P10':
        return A40:
    elif old_value == 'P11':
        return A40:
```

I am getting a syntax error from Line 3 in ArcMap (Error 000989).  I am not sure if I need double quotes around my values or not or if I am ending the expression correctly.  Can someone help me resolve the issues in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your return statement - remove the colon at the end.  i.e.:

```
def gst(old_value):
    if old_value == 'P00':
        return A91
```

Also, if A91 is not an existing variable, and you want to have it as a string - you must enclose it in quotes -> 'A91'

Comment: Thank you so much, I removed the colon and then got the second error message about A89 not being an existing variable and then added the quotes and it solved it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using all those `if...elif` statements, you might find it easier to use a dictionary:

```py
def gst(old_value):
    old = ['P00', 'P09', 'P01', 'P02', 'P03', 'P04', 'P05', 'P06', 'P10', 'P11']
    new = ['A91', 'A91', 'A89', 'A90', 'A90', 'A40', 'A40', 'A40', 'A40', 'A40']
    return dict(zip(old, new)).get(old_value)
```

Comment: I agree Paul, if I were doing this - a dictionary would be the way I would go too.  I haven't seen the .get option in the dictionary before - thanks for the tip.

Comment: @dklassen, using the `.get()` method is a bit better than the near equivalent `dict(zip(old, new))[old_value]` as the latter will return an error if the key is not found. `.get()` returns `None` if the key is not found, or will return a default value if a 2nd, optional parameter is passed to it.